# EnumType.STRING ignored by ebean and Play 2

Tags: jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have a field definition that is set as an enumeration with EnumType.STRING.

Typically, this works nicely, but on two occasions, it has ignored the EnumType attribute and used the ordinal value for the enumeration.

My declaration looks like this:

```
@Basic(optional=true) @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public StationFormat stationFormat;
```

I've tried:

1. Changing the name of the field

   It still creates it as an ordinal
2. Doing a clean compile

   Still uses ordinal value
3. Adding a second field on the same class

   Still uses ordinal value

What the heck? I had this happen before, and at some point it magically resolved itself.

-John

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem, thought I believe the underlying issue is a bug.

To workaround, add the same enum to a DIFFERENT model class. Does not matter which one, and you can delete it immediately afterwards. It will be added correctly to the new class, as well as the existing class will be amended to use the name() value rather than the ordinal.